# Get Array Of Hours from Two Dates

Tags: swift, swiftui, formatting

I am trying to build a swiftui app, i am trying to get the hours from the dates, so my dates are: 09.12.2022 09:00-09.13.2022 09:00

I have got it to tell me that there is 24 hours between the dates but i want to show the dates like 09:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00 and so on until it reaches the closing date

this is my code so far. Its returning the hours to build a foreachloop on my screen.

func getHours(times:String)-> Int{

```
    let fullNameArr : [String] = times.components(separatedBy: "-")
    
    print(fullNameArr[0])
    print(fullNameArr[1])
    
    // Create Date Formatter
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm"

    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: fullNameArr[0])!
    let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: fullNameArr[1])!
    
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let components = cal.dateComponents([.hour], from: date1, to: date2)
    let diff = components.hour!

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: diff, by: 1) {
        print(i)
    }
    return diff
    
}
```

Comment: Not every date has 24h

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to get the hour difference:

```
let endDate = Date()
let startDate = endDate - 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0

let diffHours = Calendar.current
    .dateComponents([.hour], from: startDate, to: endDate)
```

Now we are going to make a `Range` of hours from zero to `diffHours`. Then we are going to map that range of hours to an `Array` of `Date` ranging from `startDate` to `endDate` Then we are going to map to an `Array` of hour values. Then we are going to map to an `Array` of `String` formatted as `01:00`.

```
let hours = (0...(diffHours.hour ?? 0))
    .compactMap { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: startDate) }
    .map { Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: $0) }
    .map { String(format: "%02d:00", $0) }
```

`%d` tells the formatter you want an integer

`%02d` tells the formatter you want two digits with a leading zero

Now let's see what we have:

```
print("ZZZ range:", (startDate..<endDate).formatted())
print("ZZZ hours:", hours)
```

Prints:

```
ZZZ range: 6/17/22, 1:50 PM – 6/18/22, 1:50 PM
ZZZ hours: ["13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use Calendar method `nextDate(after:)` and match component minute equal to zero:

```
func getHours(times: String)-> [String] {
    
    let components = times.components(separatedBy: "-")
    guard components.count == 2,
          var start = DateFormatter.custom.date(from: components[0]),
          let end = DateFormatter.custom.date(from: components[1]),
          start < end else {
        return []
    }
    var dates: [Date] = []
    if start.minute == 0 {
        dates.append(start)
    }
    while start < end {
        guard let date = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).nextDate(after: start, matching: DateComponents(minute: 0), matchingPolicy: .strict) else {
            continue
        }
        if date < end {  // If you want to include the end date as well just remove this condition
            dates.append(date)
        }
        start = date
    }
    return dates.map(DateFormatter.time.string)
}
```

---

You will need those date formatters

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let custom: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    static let time: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

And this Date extension:

```
extension Date {
    var minute: Int {
        Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).component(.minute, from: self)
    }
}
```

---

usage:

```
let times = "09.12.2022 09:00-09.13.2022 09:00"

print(getHours(times: times))
```

This will print

> ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00"]